# Extension field of finite degree

Tags: extension-field

Let $E$ and $F$ two finite extensions of a field $K$ of degree $[E:K]=m$ and $[F:K]=n$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Show that if $\alpha\in F$ has degree $r$ on $K$ therefore $\alpha$ has degree $r$ on $E$.

What I did is,
there is an irreducible polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_rx^r \in K[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. But how can I continue ? The problem is $\alpha\notin E$ by hypothesis, no ?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question... As you said $\alpha \notin E$ we can not say much.. I guess your question is incomplete... please check the question..

Comment: Do you mean finite?

Comment: Yes, finite. Actually it's precisely the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of divisibility.

We know that $[K[\alpha]:K]=r$, but $K\subset K[\alpha]\subset F$, so $r$ divides $m$, since $m=[F:K]=[F:K[\alpha]][K[\alpha]:K]=[F:K[\alpha]]*r$.
Therefore $(r,n)=1$.

Let's assume $r>1$, since $r=1$ means $r\in K$, and the problem becomes very easy.

As you said, $\alpha\not\in E$ since $r$ doesn't divide $n$, and
$K\subset E\subset E[\alpha]$ is a tower of finite extensions, but also $K\subset K[\alpha]\subset E[\alpha]$ is a tower of extensions, so $r$ and $n$ divide $[E[\alpha]:K]$. But $[E:K]=n$, $[E[\alpha]:E]\le r$ lead to
$$
rn|[E[\alpha]:K]=[E[\alpha]:E][E:K]\le rn \implies [E[\alpha]:K]=rn \implies [E[\alpha]:E]=r
$$

Comment: can you tel me why $r$ divide $m$ and $\gcd(r,n)$ ? I don't really understand this part. Thank's :-)

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it clarifies